# exporting plotted diagram in LaTex

Tags: latex

i plotted a diagram  in latex, then i need to export it as `.jpg` or `.eps` file, here is my `.tex` code?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot coordinates {
( 338.1, 266.45 )
( 169.1, 143.43 )
( 84.5, 64.80 )
( 42.3, 34.19 )
( 21.1, 9.47 )
 };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use TikZ externalize library. And in the preamble after including `pgfplots`:

```
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
```

Now you'll get an image in a `.pdf` and can convert to whatever you want format it will be.